# how to use attributes to style to a specific element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, styles

I have one container element with a group of divs that each contain an image element within them. How do I get to apply a style to only that image, and not the other elements with the same container element?

Here is what I have so far (html):

```
  <div class="media_img_container">              
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 thumb">
          <a class="thumbnail thumbnail_overlay_container" href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" 
               src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" 
               id="media_img_01">
               <div class="thumbnail_overlay">
                 <div class="text">
                     <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i 
                 </div>
               </div>
              <button class="thumbnail_btn">
                <span class="thumbnail_btn-icon"></span>
              </button>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.thumbnail_overlay_container .thumbnail_btn{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
height: 24px;
width: 24px;
background-color: #0073aa;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 2px #0073aa;
}
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var media_img_container = $('.media_img_container');

var media_images = media_img_container.find('img');

$('a').click(function(){
    var idAttr = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
    if(idAttr){
        $('.thumbnail_btn').css('display','block');
    }
})
```

})

Comment: You are obtaining `media_images` and `idAttr` but you do nothing with these references(?).

Comment: my goal was to find a "programmatic" way to affect the style of only the element clicked, not all of them. And I wanted to use the attr method for this. The problem comes when I click on the anchor element and the thumbnail appears for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very straightforward but you can easily target any DOM element by adding an attribute, a class, or if it is structured by using that structure to your advantage.  In order:

```
$('.media_img_container img[attribute]')  // <img attribute class='...
$('.media_img_container img.myClass')     // <img class='myClass' ...
$('.media_img_container img:eq(0)')       // uses known structure
```

if you are clicking an image and want to apply a style to it:

```
$('#something').click(function() { $(this).attr('myAttr','somevalue'  });
```

Then in css  you could target this:  `.media_img_container img[myAttr=somevalue]` or just `.media_img_container`img[myAttr]`

Comment: Or even `.media_img_container img` as there don't appear to be any other images in the container.

Comment: Yeah, the question isn't clear, you can obviously just use whatever hierarchy required.   There is no `.img_container` class though.

Comment: the issue comes when I click on the anchor element and the style (i.e. thumbnail_btn) applies to all of the children elements. I wanted to use the attr method to affect only that one for which it was clicked.

Comment: @JohnnyG there are no img's inside any element with class 'thumbnail_btn' in your quesiton.